# Differential Calculus Problem - Sphere volume increasing (differentiation of algebraic functions)

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

The Air is pumped into a spherical ball which expands at a rate of 8cm^3 per second. Find the exact rate of increase of the radius of the ball when the radius is 2 cm. 
I have tried this question, with using the V=4/3(πr^3) (area of the sphere). 
It is clear that to get the answer I have to come up with a function and then differentiate it, but I can't get my head round the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $V(t)=\frac{4\pi r^3(t)}{3}.$ Thus:

$$8=\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}=4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}.$$ So, if $r=2$ you have:

$$8=16\pi \frac{dr}{dt},$$ that is

$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{1}{2\pi}.$$

Comment: Thank you. How did you get 4πr^2 (dr/dt)?

Comment: Nevermind, got it